# Iterating An Array Symmetrically

Tags: c++, c, arrays, iteration

Wasn't exactly sure how to title this, but I hope it makes sense.  I want to iterate an array forwards and then backwards, x number of times.  One option is to double the size of the array and then iterate based on mod length, thus iterating in a circular fashion.  Assuming an extremely large sequence, that could consume a lot of unnecessary memory.  Another option is this:

```
while(++i <= iterations) {
    for(j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++){
        //do something
    }
    for(j = arrayLength - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        //do something
    }
}
```

That just feels ugly though - I'm sort of repeating myself, just switching the ++/--.  I'm looking for an elegant coding approach to this.  The language should be C or C++.  Just to be very clear, I'm looking for a different algorithm.  Thanks.

Comment: There is not much choice. I guess you wouldn't like recursion either...

Comment: Elegance does not mean taking something simple and making it more complex.

Comment: If `//do something` is the same in both cases, you can put it in a function (in case you haven't thought of this).

Comment: Probably not the direction you want to go, but I would suggest `for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)` instead of `while(++i <= iterations)` in favour of readability (even if only slightly so).

Comment: For the title: "Boustrophedonic array iteration".

Comment: @ScepticalJule Would not prefer recursion, but challenge you to a solution.

Comment: @Chad My use of elegance is, "pleasingly ingenious and simple," the code should be just as simple.

Comment: @Dukeling Appreciate the thought.  While vs. for and the do something are not core to my question.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Nice! I also considered palindromic.  To be quite precise, the sequence I am dealing with is a morphic word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives elegance at the cost of some efficiency:

```
while(++i <= iterations) {
    for(j = 0; j < twiceArrayLength; ++j) {
        k = min(j, arrayLengthMinusOne) - max(0, j - arrayLength);
        doSomething(k);
    }
}
```

Example: When `arrayLength` is `5`, then `j` will run from `0` to `9`, and the corresponding value of `k` will run from `0` up to `4` and then from `4` down to `0`.

EDIT: As per your request, to start at a different point in the array, you can do this:

```
while(++i <= iterations) {
    endPoint = startPoint + twiceArrayLength;
    for(j = startPoint; j < endPoint; ++j) {
        jModTwiceArrayLength = j % twiceArrayLength;
        k = min(jModTwiceArrayLength, arrayLengthMinusOne) - max(0, jModTwiceArrayLength - arrayLength);
        doSomething(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising.

Comment: I guess you could also factor out `arrayLength - 1` into an outer variable `arrayLengthMinusOne`, and the cost per iteration wouldn't be too prohibitive.

Comment: Do you think you could modify this so that the starting point could be anywhere in the array?

Comment: Sure -- Just loop `j` from `startingPoint` to `startingPoint + twiceArrayLength` and calculate `k` using `j % twiceArrayLength`.  You'd need an extra evaluation for the `j % twiceArrayLength` operation, but that's about it.  Shout if you'd like to see the code.

Answer (score 2):

[`boost::adaptors::reverse`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html) could come handy here:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

while (i++ < iterations) {
    for (auto i : array) /* do something */ ;
    for (auto i : boost::adaptors::reverse(array)) /* do something */ ;
}
```

In C++14, we'll also have [`std::rbegin` and `std::rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin), sou you could write something like:

```
auto rb = std::rbegin(array);
auto re = std::rend(array);
while (rb != re) {
    // do something
    ++rb;
}
```

That is if you're working with plain arrays. Most of standard containers already come with `rbegin()` and `rend()` methods that give you reverse iterators.

Comment: Cool that non-member `rbegin` and `rend` got added. Since one reason I heard against them was that `begin` and `end` were only strictly needed because of range-based `for` I guess we'll see `rfor` in C++16 then ;)

Comment: Edited my question.  I'm really looking for a different algorithm, not a library that utilizes the same algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a different approach. Not going to claim it's necessarily better by any particular criteria, though.

```
int dir = 1;
int start = 0, end = arrayLength - 1;

while (++i <= (iterations << 1))
{  int j = start;

   do
   { // something
     j += dir;
   } while (j != end);

   dir = -dir;
   int tmp = start; start = end; end = tmp;
}
```

I actually think that's a bit convoluted, and a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen, but at least you're not "repeating yourself". And it might be "elegant" in the "clever" sense... Not so much in the "simple" sense.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track with a different approach.  Limiting to one "do something" is better.  This needs to be cleaned up a bit more though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cleaned up". I suppose you could hide the last line with an appropriately defined inline `swap()` function, and combine the increment/decrement into the `while` condition expression, but given that the question basically just showed the outline of an algorithm, I figured an alternative outline would be the place to start...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps slightly nicer?

```
j = -1;

while(++i <= iterations) {
    while(++j < arrayLength){
        //do something
    }
    while(--j >= 0){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, can you operate on the elements in unison?

```
while(++i <= iterations) {
    for(j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++){
        //do something with array[j]
        //do something with array[arrayLength - j - 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe more brief, but it does take a bit longer to figure out what's going on there, and it would be even more so if you start adding to the code.

Comment: @Dukeling That's what code comments are for. In either case you're going to need to explain what's happening (probably) because they both take a moment or two to figure out otherwise.  That said, op said his/her approach felt "ugly", and IMO this is slightly less so.

Comment: You don't need comments for the code in the question (at least not for the parts of the code provided). It's very easy to see that that's 2 simple for loops.

Comment: @Dukeling Your *opinion* (as it is, as opposed to fact) has been noted. I happen to disagree, I feel mine's easier to read.

Comment: @Madbreaks Unfortunately, the sequence is critical.  Nice thought though.

Comment: How about my first suggestion, then?

Comment: @Madbreaks I updated my questions.  I'm looking for a better algorithm, preferably one that only has one block for "do something."

Comment: I'd suggest up-voting answers that you feel were helpful, in that case people will be more likely to continue to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(++i <= iterations)
{
   for(auto it = array.begin(); it!=array.end(); ++it)
   { //do something }

   for(auto it = array.rbegin(); it!=array.rend(); ++it)
   { //do something }

}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a different algorithm.